# Delete unflushed file from Azure Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

To upload a file to ADL first you need to:

- do a put request with the `?resource=file` parameters (this creates a file on the ADL)
- append data to the file with the `?action=append&position=<N>` parameters
- lastly, you need to flush the data with `?action=flush&position=<FILE_SIZE>`

My question is:

**Is there a way to tell the server how long the data should live if it is not flushed(written).**

Since you need to create a file first to write data into it, there might be scenarios where the flush does not happen, and you are stuck with an empty file in the data lake.

I could not find anything on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update) about this.

Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 0219:**

If you just call the `append api`, but not call the `flush api`, then the uncommitted data will be saved in azure within **7 days**.

The uncommitted data will be deleted automatically after 7 days and cannot be deleted from the your end.

---

**Origianl:**

The SDK for Azure Datalake Storage Gen2 is ready, and you can use it to operate ADLS Gen2 more easier than using rest api.

If you're using .NET/c#, there is a SDK for Azure Datalake Storage Gen2: [Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/).

Here is the official doc for how to use this SDK to operate ADLS Gen2, and the c# code below is used to delete a file / upload a file for ADLS Gen2:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountName = "xxx";
            string accountKey = "xxx";

            StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential =
        new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

            string dfsUri = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

            DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient
                (new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential);

            DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemClient("w22");
            DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("t2");

            // use this line of code to delete a file
            //directoryClient.DeleteFile("22.txt");


            //use the code below to upload a file
            //DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.CreateFile("22.txt");
            //FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("d:\\foo2.txt");

            //long fileSize = fileStream.Length;
            //fileClient.Append(fileStream, offset: 0);
            //fileClient.Flush(position: fileSize);

            Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

For Java, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java).

For Python, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python).

Comment: My question is not how to upload a file, I can already do that.
I need more info about what happens with unflushed files and how to delete them.

Comment: @3Jumph, ok. And I want to confirm that you want to know how long the uncommitted data(via append operation) will live in azure? And how to delete the uncommitted data(not the empty file)?

Comment: Young yes, I am interested in what happens to the data.
I also want to know if there is a way to delete the file (except the REST API delete operation) if the file was not flushed.

I hope this clears it up

Comment: @3Jumph, I have updated my answer. Please let me know if you still have more issues:)

Comment: Could you please point me to the source of the information? I wouldn't need anything else after that.

Comment: @3Jumph, I got the feedback via email from the support team. I can attach the screenshot of the email if you like it.